# Where can I find the the SQLite binary SQLite.Interop.dll?

Tags: .net, sqlite

There are supposed to be an x86 and an x64 version of the library SQLite.Interop.dll so that you can work on either machine architecture.  However I cannot find where this binary comes from.  I've downloaded the .NET 4.0 precompiled binary packages from [system.data.sqlite.org](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) (both statically-linked and non), and they just aren't in the zip packages.  I don't get it.  They are referenced several places in the documentation yet they are not provided in the downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like at least one place you can get it from is NuGet?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/

Not a fan of NuGet farting up my solutions, but I suppose I can use it to download the package and check in the libraries on my own.